# What's the problem of this generic code(if returns without casting (T) it fails)

Tags: java, generics, extends

When i build this code with maven, it shows me the error "PRequest cannot be converted to T".

1. if i cast the return value of 'getRequest(Object params)' method of Parent 
   build succeed.
2. if i write is as 
   public abstract PRequest getRequest(Map params);
   build succeed.

```java
public abstract class Parent<T extends CommonRequest> {
    public abstract T getRequest(Map<String, Object> params);

    public T getRequest(Object params) {
        // ERROR PRequest cannot be converted to T
        return params instanceof Map ?
            getRequest((Map)params) :
            getRequest(JacksonUtil.getMapper().convertValue(params, Map.class));
    }
    ...
}

public class Child extends Parent<PRequest> {
    @Override
    public PRequest getRequest(Map<String, Object> params) {
        return new PRequest();
    }
    ...
}

public class PRequest extends CommonRequest {
    ...
}
```

i want to know why error occurs when i write return type as T with out casting like "(T)getRequest((Map)params)"

Comment: *"// ERROR PRequest cannot be converted to T"*: the error I'm getting is *"Type mismatch: cannot convert from CommonRequest to T"*. Are you sure your code is as posted?

Comment: yes! 100%..  additional.. when i run this code on tomcat, it works o.o;;;; /// And Actually error msg could be not correct but, if you try to cast the result in your test, it might success to build without error